# vb.net how to hide index in combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

net and I dont know how to hide a specific item in my combobox.
I have two comboboxes(cmbo_frm and cmbo_to) and its contents are from my database. What I want to do is when I click a value in cmbo_frm that value is automatically hidden in cmbo_to.

```
Try
            If cmbo_to.SelectedIndex <> -1 And cmbo_frm.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                If txtbox_ftype.Text = "Regular" Then
                    Data = "SELECT [Fare].Rfare FROM [Mc_Koy].[dbo].[Fare],[Mc_Koy].[dbo].[User] where [Fare].Locfrom = '" & cmbo_frm.SelectedValue.ToString & "' AND [Fare].Locto = '" & cmbo_to.SelectedValue.ToString & "'"
                    Command = New SqlCommand(Data, Connection)
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
                    dr = Command.ExecuteReader
                    With dr
                        dr.Read()
                        txt_fare.Text = .Item(0)
                        dr.Close()
                    End With
                Else
                    Data = "SELECT [Fare].Dfare FROM [Mc_Koy].[dbo].[Fare],[Mc_Koy].[dbo].[User] where [Fare].Locfrom = '" & cmbo_frm.SelectedValue.ToString & "' AND [Fare].Locto = '" & cmbo_to.SelectedValue.ToString & "'"
                    Command = New SqlCommand(Data, Connection)
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
                    dr = Command.ExecuteReader
                    With dr
                        dr.Read()
                        txt_fare.Text = .Item(0)
                        dr.Close()
                    End With
                If cmbo_frm.SelectedValue.ToString <> cmbo_to.SelectedValue.ToString Then
                    btn_save.Show()
                Else
                    cmbo_to.SelectedIndex = -1
                End If
                End If
            End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

please Reload `txt_to` from the database right after "click a value in cmbo_frm" and then execute the following code

```
For i = 0 To cmbo_to.Items.Count - 1
    If cmbo_to.Items.Item(i).ToString.Trim = cmbo_frm.Text.Trim Then
        cmbo_to.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```